# Egit can't fetch README changes

Tags: eclipse, egit

I'm using Eclipse 4.2.1 and EGIT. I've done the following:

1. Created an account on Github.
2. Created a Repo and initialized it with a readMe from Github at the time I created it.
3. Cloned the repo using EGIT.
4. Created a Java project in Eclipse, a single class with a main method.
5. Share the project with GIT. Team-> Share Project-> GIT
6. In the Configure GIT repo dialog: Selected the repo I just cloned from Github.
7. Do a commit.
8. Push to remote origin.
9. Go back to Github and make a change to the readMe. (This shows in the commits on Github)
10. Fetch the changes with EGIT.

The changed readMe is shown in the remote tracking branch in EGIT but not in my local master branch. I tried refreshing but it still doesn't work. After doing this my local master is one behind and I can't push. I get rejected non-fast forward.

I can fix this by creating a new local branch based on HEAD then merging it into my local master. But why is this happening? Is anyone else experiencing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetching only gets the changes from github into the remote tracking branch (imagine this as a kind of index) on your local machine, but not into your working directory (the real files you edit). You still have to merge the remote changes into your local branch (which you can do by expanding the repository node Branches -> Remote Tracking -> origin/master and selecting "Merge" in the context menu).

If you always just want to fetch and immediately merge the remote changes, use the "Pull" command instead of the "Fetch" command, it is a combination of fetch and merge.